# IndexOf predicate?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, collections

I want to find the index of an element in a list maching a certain predicate, is there a better way to do it than:

```
var index = list.IndexOf(list.Find(predicate));
```

?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Are you looking for [`List<T>.FindIndex(predicate)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx)?

Comment: Or Array.FindIndex(T[], Func<T,bool>)

Comment: Unfortunately for SilverLight legacy code, FindIndex() appears to not exist